# .htaccess redirection rule pagination

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Good evening, I'm using .htaccess to do some redirects on a news site. It works on most of the site except the index page. I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.nnn$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.nnn/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.domain.nnn/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^page([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

The last line is the problem, because if I want to go to:

```
domain.nnn/page2
```

It redirects me to:

```
domain.nnn/?page=2
```

How can I solve it? Thanks for your help. Regards

Comment: Just `/page$1` should do. What's the `?` for? It is only used to start a query and there is none in your example.

Comment: Hello, I also use this line that works well:

`RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9a-z\_\-\.]+)/page([0-9]+)/?$ posts.php?post_cat_slug=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]`

The problem happens when I want to make pagination in the index.

Comment: I fixed it, I just left this `?page=$1` and now it works very well. Thank you!